# Export SSRS Report to Excel but then add formulas and formatting to create a worksheet that users can add own data (Power Automate?)

Tags: excel, reporting-services, power-automate, insert-update

I have created a report in SSRS that is several tables. I can export the report to Excel easily enough but the users want to have the ability to input their own numbers in a line below the tables.  This line (y) would be followed with another summary line(y+z, or x-y=z, whatever). Yes, they can open the report insert extra lines, add formulas and formatting... but since this report will be run monthly and there are 11 tables in this report it would be nice if there is a Power Automate solution to add lines, formulas and formats or some other solution. Feel free to post potential solutions or teaching resources that may allow me to piece together a solution. Thank you.

I haven't tried anything yet. The only solution I can do at the moment is create a Excel template where I paste the exported spreadsheet and it gets 'lookedup' by a second tab with the proper/end formatted spreadsheet. Would like to modernize the solution(and learn)....although learning VBA is not solution I am looking for....

Comment: Power Automate can insert new rows on a table inside a worksheet, but it's difficult to show a solution without seeing your entire problem.

Comment: I agree and tested out Power Automate, and it worked great but what happens when the table length changes? The basic script I created would input rows in the middle of the table if the table has more rows. Is there there function to look for the 1st blank row, then the 2nd blank row, and 3rd to insert at the end of each table.

Comment: Maybe you should open a question around your issue as to how to add rows.

Comment: As far as I know, the task will create a new row at the end of the target table. And I agree with @Skin.

Comment: I used the Power Automate script on another SSRS export with a shorter initial table and it did indeed add the rows and formulas to the middle of the next table.  So a basic power automate script is not the solution. I have added the extra rows in SSRS so adding rows is no longer the issue.  But I will ask another question around adding formulas.  Thanks!